# Where should I ask a question about LinkedIn?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a *specific* question about how to use LinkedIn more effectively regarding my career. I'm a graduate student but the question is about industry.

Which site would be the best for it? [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour), [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour), [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tour), or someplace else?

Comment: Why was my comment here, asking for clarification, removed? If it would have been removed *after* the question got closed, I'd understand, but this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how this works.  Just knowing that your question is about Linked In does not tell us whether it would be on-topic on any Stack Exchange site, or which Stack Exchange site.  Not all questions can be asked somewhere on the Stack Exchange network.

So, I don't think we can answer your question without knowing what you want to ask.  If you don't want to explain what your question is here, I suggest you take a look at the help center for the sites you mentioned, and spend some time browsing around, to learn more about the norms and expectations of each of those sites.

Answer (score 7):

[The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour) is a community to help you with questions about the workplace. You can ask questions on specific issues encountered navigating a professional environment, real problems or questions that you’ve encountered in a workplace.

[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) is the place to ask questions about using a website which behaves like an application, augmented browsing extensions that directly relate to the use of a web application ([Greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) scripts for a web application, etc.).

[Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tour) deals with questions on academic careers, requirements and expectations of students, postdocs, or professors, inner workings of research departments, academic writing and publishing, studying and teaching at institutions of higher education (universities, colleges, …), etc.

If your questions deals with using LinkedIn to find a job or promote your career, or on how to use LinkedIn *professionally* / effectively  in your industry post it in *Workplace*. If you want to know how to *use* LinkedIn properly, ask in *Web Applications*. If you want to know how to use LinkedIn for *academic purposes*—how to cite LinkedIn posts in papers, or post your papers in LinkedIn platform, etc.—post it in *Academia*.

Follow the links I have posted and they all also describe the kind of questions that aren't allowed.